# Google App Script to take form responses submitted by teachers on their students and produce formatted PDF student reports

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not a programmer but, with help, I managed to make a Google Apps Script which takes reports, submitted by teachers on their students, to the Form Responses Sheet, and then selects all responses which pertain to each student, and generates that student's report, inserting the school's logo into the header and the Principal's signature image after the last reported subject, as a PDF.
However, there are 10-15 teachers submitting reports on 50-60 students, each of whom takes an average of 6-8 subjects, so I end up with around 400 rows in the dataset, from which I need to generate around 60 individual student reports, and my GAS is taking longer than the 6 minute execution time. I could order form responses by student name and break down the dataset onto a few sheets and run the script on each, but the preference would be to convert my very beginner-level code into something which is more efficient and can do the job in less time, whilst making less calls to Google services.

This is the current code. It uses the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` method, where `MainSheet` contains the Form Responses submitted by teachers, and detailsSheet contains values of items which need to be inserted into every report (school logo image, principal signature image, semester, year and the Folder ID where I want the generated report PDF files to be stored):

```
function createDocuments() {
// Enable the Advanced Drive Service

function enableAdvancedDriveService() {
  return DriveApp.getStorageUsed();
}

  // Access the active Google Sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Access the main sheet containing student data
  var mainSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MainSheet");
  
  // Access the sheet containing additional details
  var detailsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("DetailsSheet");
  
  // Get the data range for the main sheet
  var dataRange = mainSheet.getDataRange();
  
  // Get all data from the main sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  // Create an object to store data for each student
  var studentData = {};
  
  // Loop through each row of data (skipping header row)
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    
    // Extract data from the row
    var studentName = row[1];
    var program = row[2];
    var teacherName = row[0];
    var subject = row[3];
    var typeGrade = row[4]; // Assuming Grade Type is in column 8 (change as needed)
    var percentageGrade = row[5];
    var letterGrade = row[6];
    var remarks = row[7];
    
    // Check if student data exists in the object
    if (!studentData[studentName]) {
      // Initialize student data object if it doesn't exist
      studentData[studentName] = {
        "program": program,
        "subjects": []
      };
    }
    
    // Add subject data to the student's subjects array
    studentData[studentName]["subjects"].push({
      "teacherName": teacherName,
      "subject": subject,
      "typeGrade": typeGrade,
      "percentageGrade": percentageGrade,
      "letterGrade": letterGrade,
      "remarks": remarks
    });
  }
  
  // Loop through each student in the student data object
  for (var studentName in studentData) {
  if (studentData.hasOwnProperty(studentName)) {
    var student = studentData[studentName];
    
    // Create filename for the report
    var programInitials = (student["program"] === "High School") ? "HS" : "MS";
    var semester = detailsSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
    var semesterShort = semester.slice(0, 2); // Extract first two letters of semester
    var year = detailsSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    var yearShort = year.toString().slice(-2); // Extract last two digits of year
    var typeReport = detailsSheet.getRange("B5").getValue(); // Assuming Report Type is in cell B6 (change as needed)
    var filename = studentName + " " + programInitials + " " + semesterShort + yearShort + " " + typeReport + " Report.pdf";
    
    // Create a new Google Doc
    var doc = DocumentApp.create(filename);
      
      // Access the body of the document
      var body = doc.getBody();
     // Access the header of the document
     var header = doc.addHeader();

      // Insert School Logo image
      var logoImageFileId = detailsSheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
      var logoFile = DriveApp.getFileById(logoImageFileId);
      var logoImg = header.appendImage(logoFile.getBlob());
      var styles = {};
      styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
      logoImg.getParent().setAttributes(styles);   
    
    // Insert student details
    var reportHeader = studentName.toUpperCase() + "\n" +
                       student["program"].toUpperCase() + " - " + typeReport.toUpperCase() + " REPORT\n" +
                       semester.toUpperCase() + ", " + year;
    body.appendParagraph(reportHeader).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setBold(true);
    
    // Loop through each subject for the student
    for (var j = 0; j < student["subjects"].length; j++) {
      var subjectData = student["subjects"][j];
      
      // Insert subject and teacher details on the same line
      body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty paragraph
      body.appendParagraph(subjectData["subject"] + " - " + subjectData["teacherName"]).setFontSize(12).setBold(true);
      body.appendParagraph(subjectData["typeGrade"] + ": " + subjectData["percentageGrade"] + "% (" + subjectData["letterGrade"] + ")").setFontSize(12).setBold(false);
      body.appendParagraph("Remarks: " + subjectData["remarks"]);
      body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty paragraph
    }
    
    // Insert Principal's signature and stamp image
      var signatureImageFileId = detailsSheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
      var signatureFile = DriveApp.getFileById(signatureImageFileId);
      body.appendImage(signatureFile.getBlob());
    
    // Insert disclaimer below Principal's signature and stamp image
    var disclaimer = "Please note that this document has no official validity and is solely for informative purposes.";
    body.appendParagraph(""); // Add an empty paragraph
    body.appendParagraph(disclaimer).setFontSize(8).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    
    // Save the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    
    // Convert the document to PDF
    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');

    // Get the folder ID where you want to store the generated reports
    var folderId = detailsSheet.getRange("B6").getValue();
    
    // Access the specified folder
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Create the PDF file in the specified folder
    var pdfFile = folder.createFile(pdf);
    
    // Delete the temporary Google Doc
    DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  }
}
}
```

If required, I can provide a `MainSheet` and `DetailsSheet` with a sample dataset which could be used for testing.